# eval and Obfuscation of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clojure, eval, obfuscation

I wish to keep certain JavaScript functions on the server and then send them via JSON as when required.
I will then eval() these functions and use them accordingly.
Now my problem is, If I minify the source file using Clojure or some other Obfuscation library then will the eval'ed function have any chance to conflict with my Obfuscated JS file?

For Reference :

```
src.js <- Has the eval() call on an JSON property

response.func = "function someAsyncFunc() { //that does nothing as of now ; }";

var zixuy = eval(response.func); //Notice the name of the variable, its a result of Obfuscation
```

Now, once the function is eval'ed, are there any chances that there won't be any weird things that might happen within that function IF there are any variables within it that depend on the Parent's scope.
If Yes, then is there a workaround/solution for the same?

**UPDATE**:
I was finally able to drill this basic sense into him after all.

Comment: 1) Yes, there could be conflicts. 2) The same way you avoid conflicts in your regular JS code. Bonus) For anyone who wants to 'decode' your javascript, this method actually makes it *easier*, not harder: by clearly denoting the code you think needs to be 'private'.

Comment: You shouldn't have any javascript that *needs* to be obfuscated in the first place.

Comment: I know, but I can't help it. I'm trying to make an argument against that with my colleague, but unfortunately, I can't come with the an Example that I could use to explain it to him.